# How do I install Windows on a Mac using Boot Camp?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, boot-camp

I need to install Windows on my Mac. I have read that I need to use Boot Camp to do this. However, when I tried, I got the following error on the first step:

> The startup disk must be formatted as a single Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume or already partitioned by Boot Camp Assistant for installing Windows.

Comment: The problem is that I already have partition with linux Ubuntu and i can't delete it.

Comment: @Dani  Make sure to associate your accounts on Stack Overflow and Super User.  You will then regain ownership of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. 
If you use Boot Camp Assistant, your start-up disk have only a single partition (i.e., do not partition the hard disk to reserve space for Windows by yourself). The Boot Camp Assistant will help you to do so.

Go to Disk Utility and delete those partitions, and then run Boot Camp Assistant again.