# How to install Windows XP via Bootcamp when there is a 3rd partiton that cannot be removed?

Tags: macos, boot-camp, truecrypt

I have three partitions on my computer:

- System partition named "macintosh" with HFS+ filesystem **journaled** and Mac OS X installed (no encryption).
- Non system partition named "vault" with HFS+ filesystem and my data are stored on this partition (encrypted with Truecrypt)
- System partition named "windows" with NTFS filesystem and Windows is not installed (no encryption)

I have tried to install Windows XP on the "windows" partition via Bootcamp but Bootcamp refuses to start the installation and displays the following message: The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition.

I believe it is because there is the "truecrypt" partition in the middle since in the past  I succeeded at installing Windows on the "windows partition" when there was no "truecrypt partition.

**Has any succeeded at installing Windows XP with this configuration ?** Ideally, I would like not to have to remove my truecrypt partition.

FYI:

Here is the partition table:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *320.1 GB   disk0

   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1

   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh               100.0 GB   disk0s2

   3:                  Apple_HFS vault                   200.1 GB   disk0s3

   4:                  Apple_HFS WINDOWS                 19.4 GB    disk0s4
```

Comment: Looks like it is not possible: http://superuser.com/questions/261263/how-do-i-install-windows-on-a-mac-using-boot-camp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried without using bootcamp at all?  Put in the windows install DVD/CD and restart the computer while holding down the alt/option key.  That should get you to the boot manager and you should be able to boot into the windows cd.  From there follow on through with the normal installation choosing the WINDOWS partition as the destination.

Comment: After posting the question, I tried that and it works just fine.